# Norms involving positive operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let's say we have $A \leq B$. Is it then true that $||Ax|| \leq ||Bx||$ (where $x, A, B$ all belong to the same finite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$)?

Comment: Uh?? How are $\,x,A,B\,$ all "in the same space"? What is $\,A\le B\,$ in a vector space? And what is $\,Ax\,$ (product of vectors) in a vector space??

Comment: Maybe the question makes sense if it says "Let's say we have $||A|| \leq ||B||$.  Is it then true that $||Ax|| \leq ||Bx||?$

Comment: Nope, all I have is that $A$ and $B$ are positive operators such that $A \leq B$. Is it possible to say anything at all about $||Ax||$ and $||Bx||$?

Comment: There are two different ways we can view $A \leq B$. It could either mean that $\|Ax\|\leq\|Bx\|$ for all $x\in H$ OR it could mean that $\|A\|\leq \|B\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ here is the operator norm.

In the first case, the answer is obvious. In the second case, we cannot (in general) conclude anything about these two quantities.

Comment: The OP has repeated, by 2nd time, the weird condition $\,A\le B\,$ ...Unless he explains what does this mean I see no meaning to this question and perhaps I will vote to close it later.

Comment: By definition, as far as I am aware, doesn't it just mean that $A$ and $B$ are positive operators such that $B - A$ is a positive operator in $H$ as well?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern Most likely: $A\leq B$ means $(Ax,x)\leq (Bx,x)$ for all $x$. That is: the operator $B-A$ is positive (in the sense of operators on $H$, which is actually nonnegative, in a way).

Comment: @wemblem Correct. Except that $A$ and $B$ need not be positive when we write $A\leq B$. Apparently it is a further assumption here.

Comment: @julien: I think saying that $ A \leq B $ requires both $ A $ and $ B $ to be at least self-adjoint operators.

Comment: @HaskellCurry True. This is a partial order on self-adjoint elements. I do not consider it otherwise. I  made it clearer in my answer.

Comment: A simple counterexample comes from $ -2I \leq I $. Of course, if both $ A $ and $ B $ are required to be positive, then a counterexample is a little harder to find.

Comment: @HaskellCurry The title says: for positive operators... It is indeed trivial otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Counterexample:**
$$
A=\left(\matrix{1&1\\1&1}\right)\qquad B=\left(\matrix{2&1\\1&1}\right)
$$

**Details:** Your question needs some context. In operator theory, this reads: is the function $f(t)=t^2$ operator monotone on $[0,+\infty)$, i.e does $A\leq B$ imply $f(A)\leq f(B)$ for every self-adjoint matrices with nonnegative spectrum? [For instance](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Operator_monotone_function), $g(t)=\sqrt{t}$ is operator monotone on $[0,+\infty)$. But $f(t)=t^2$ is not, as the above example shows.

**Positive operators:** An operator $A$ in $B(H)$ is called positive if and only if one of the following equivalent assertions holds. In this case, one writes $A\geq 0$.

1) $A$ is self-adjoint and $(Ax,x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in H$ (note that the latter implies the former in the complex case by polarization, but not in the real case).

2) $A$ is self-adjoint with nonnegative spectrum.

3) There exists $B$ self-adjoint such that $A=B^2$.

**Partial order:** For every self-adjoint operators $A,B$, one writes $A\leq B$ if $B-A\geq 0$. This defines a partial order. You question may be restated as follows:
$$
0\leq A\leq B\quad\Rightarrow?\quad A^2\leq B^2.
$$
Indeed, 
$$
\|Bx\|^2-\|Ax\|^2=(Bx,Bx)-(Ax,Ax)=(B^2x,x)-(A^2x,x)=((B^2-A^2)x,x).
$$

**Counterexample check:** It is easily seen that $A$ and $B$ are positive, as they are self-adjoint with spectra $\{0,2\}$ and $\{\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\}$. Now $B-A\geq 0$ as it is self-adjoint with spectrum is $\{0,1\}$. But $B^2-A^2$ has determinant $-1$, so it is not positive.

**Commuting case:** If we assume that $A$ and $B$ commute, the result holds. With matrices, you can prove it easily by simultaneous diagonalization in an orthonormal basis. I will now give a proof which works in any dimension.

Write $B^2-A^2=(B-A)(A+B)$. Then observe that $B-A$ and $A+B$ are two commuting positive operators. Write $B-A=C^2$ and $A+B=D^2$ with $C=\sqrt{B-A}$ and $D=\sqrt{A+B}$ the unique positive square roots given by continuous functional calculus for normal operators. Since $B-A$ and $A+B$ commute, $C$ and $D$ commute by functional calculus. Therefore $B^2-A^2=C^2D^2=(CD)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: There is a weak converse. If $ x \mapsto x^{2} $ is an operator-monotone function for a $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A $, then $ A $ must be commutative. This follows from the monotone version of the Stinespring Factorization Theorem.

Comment: @LeonardTristanHuang Interesting, thanks! Do you have a reference?

Comment: Yes, I do. A proof may be found in the article [*On Characterizations of Commutativity of C$ ^{\ast} $-Algebras*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-12/S0002-9939-03-06991-0/S0002-9939-03-06991-0.pdf), published in Proceedings of the AMS, Volume $ 131 $, Number $ 12 $.

Comment: @LeonardTristanHuang Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeonardHuang the result you mention is known as Ogasawara's theorem, and it was known already in the fifties (T. Ogasawara, *A theorem on operator algebras*, J. Sci. Hiroshima Univ. Ser. A, vol. 18 (1955), pp. 307–309). See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334791/), where I give a proof based on representation theory of $C^*$-algebras.